# Unable to print value name after creating GUI using Tkinter package

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I wrote a code to pop up a box to enter the values in that using Tkinter. After the mainloop(), when I'm trying to print the value which I gave in the box, it's throwing error. The code is below

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
nameLabel = Label(root, text="Please Enter Table Name or Table ID")
ent = Entry(root, bd=5)

def getName():
    #print("Table Name is : ", ent.get())
    table = ent.get()
    print(table)
    root.destroy()

submit = Button(root, text ="Submit", command = getName)

nameLabel.pack()
ent.pack()

submit.pack(side = BOTTOM) 
root.mainloop()

table1 = table
print(table)
```

The error given is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "input_table_name.py", line 22, in <module>
    table1 = table
NameError: name 'table' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the variable `table` inside a function, which means it is local and cannot be used outside. You could use the `global` keyword to make the variable global.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
nameLabel = Label(root, text="Please Enter Table Name or Table ID")
ent = Entry(root, bd=5)

def getName():
    #print("Table Name is : ", ent.get())
    global table 
    table = ent.get()
    print(table)
    root.destroy()

submit = Button(root, text ="Submit", command = getName)

nameLabel.pack()
ent.pack()

submit.pack(side = BOTTOM) 
root.mainloop()

table1 = table
print(table)
```

Comment: It's giving error on global line.
  File "input1.py", line 10
    global table = ent.get()
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, you must first declare it global, then assign the value. I have edited the answer.